# Is this sequence is dense?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Define $S _m, _n = $ n th smallest square number which is bigger or same than $10^ {m-1}$and smaller than $10^m$

Then is the sequence $ \frac{S_m,_n}   {10^m}$ is dense in (0,1) or arbitary small$\epsilon$>0 ($\epsilon$,1)????

+mycondition wasnot accurate
$\epsilon$>0.1 should be added

Comment: If $m:=1$ then you will have $3$ squares between $1$ and $10$ so for $m=1$, $S_{m,n}$ is defined only for $n=1,2,3$ right ? More generally, $m$ being fixed you have only a finite number of elements well defined in your sequence... Or maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: A *sequence* is usually a function from $\Bbb N$ and the argument is written as a subscript: $a_n$ is a value of $a$ function for argument $n$. However your 'S' has two subscripts, $m$ and $n$, so probably one of them is a variable argument (the sequence term index) and the other one is a constant parameter. But I can't guess which is which...

Answer (score 1):

Observe that : $ 10^{m-1} < S_{m,n} < 10^m \Rightarrow 1/10 < S_{m,n}/10^m < 1$

which means that it cannot be dense in the interval $(0,1/10)$.

So it cannot be dense in $(0,1)$ or any $(\epsilon, 1)$ for $\epsilon < 1/10.$

Comment: Sorryi edited mycondition iknow there is cauchry sequence converging to any rational number in such range but i dont know how to prpve there is such sequence converging to irrationalnumbrr